# dotnet build fails to manage embedded resources

Tags: .net, build, resources, resx

```
>dotnet --info

 Runtime Environment:
  OS Name:     Windows
  OS Version:  10.0.14393
  OS Platform: Windows
  RID:         win10-x64
  Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0 (tested with 1.0.1 as well)
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new class library project (under VS2017, last update)
- Add a Foo.resx file (with designer)
- Add a Foo.fr.resx file
- Go to the project directory
- Execute `dotnet build`

Result :

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4072,5):
>   error MSB3030: **Could not copy the file**
>   **"obj\Debug\fr\ProjectName.resources.dll" because it was not found.**
>   [C:\Projects\SolutionName\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj]

I have wasted too much time on that (hacks / researches / git issues digging).
Is that a bug ?

---

**Note that there's no problem using one single file Foo.resx.** (But I need multiple cultures)

Comment: Git issue : https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6089

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem and I was able to resolve it. I found helpful info on this link: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6032

As Visual Studio build works ok, it appears that Visual Studio uses different build process then dotnet build.
Firstly, execute msbuild for your solution like:
`msbuild ConsoleApp.sln` and then run `dotnet build`.